# Unity/C# If-Statement is always true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, input, boolean

Why is this always true?

```
public float speed;
    bool working = false;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        skilling = false;
        speed = 3f;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 playerInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0);
        transform.position = transform.position + playerInput.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        
        if(speed >= 500f)
            {
                print("test");
            }
    }
```

originally i wanted to make the condition based on the "working" boolean, aswell as Key Input. It was always true.

I am losing my mind..

test
test
test
test
test
test

I tried the If-Statement with the Float as in the example, with a bool and also with a collision. It was always true. I must have messed up somewhere, but i cannot find it.

Edit:
Complete Code:
`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed;
    bool working = false;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        speed = 3f;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 playerInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0);
        transform.position = transform.position + playerInput.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        
        if(speed >= 500f)
            {
                print("test");
            }
    }
    /*void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.tag == "Skill")
            {
                //skilling = true;
            }
        else skilling = false;
    }*/
}
```

`
I removed the public from the speed variable, still true.

Comment: Given the code shown, I don't see how that `if` condition would *ever* be `true`.  The value of `speed` is only ever set once, and to a value which is most certainly lower than the value in the condition.

Comment: @David I'm assuming the speed variable here is getting manipulated from somewhere else

Comment: Is there any other code that modifies the speed variable?  You are not showing the complete class, could you provide us the entirety of the code?  As it stands now, this condition would always be false.

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya: That's likely true, but it's of little help in the question as presented.

Comment: I don't know under what conditions you want to change the 'working' boolean.
Overall, very little is needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1- Make sure you did not modify the speed variable from the inspector since it's public.

2- Make sure other classes are not changing the speed variable at the start.

Comment: Thank you for the comment,

I tried making the float private and i declared it in the start function. In the Inspector it has the value 5, which is still lower than 500

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for wasting your time, i have found the solution. I had a loop in another Script that also returned "test". Thats me getting mad for 2 hours for a stupid reason again.

Comment: Don't worry, all of us have been or will be in a situation like that XD

Comment: In the future a) make this `Debug.Log("test", this);` instead => clicking on the message in the console will highlight the responsible object ;) and b) look at the stacktrace in the log message -> it will tell you what exact component, method code line etc it belongs to ...